# Can I add a button next to Share and Follow to open a application page?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to add a button like "Share" or "Follow" next to Share or Follow button in the picture.

I want button to open an application page preferably on same master page without redirect.

As visible in this picture

[image]

IS it possible ?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking for where & how to customize the markup & styling of the masterpage to add your custom button? Or you need something like javascript to open an SP modal (in which you could load your application page)?

Answer (score 1):

The area with the share and follow buttons is called "Promoted Actions". You can create a control and attach it to the "`PromotedActions` Delegate Control". Here's an example:

http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-some-new-delegatecontrol-additions-to-the-sharepoint-2013-master-pages

However to do this, you need to create a farm solution. If for some reason you want to avoid a farm solution, there might be a way to create a new link in the `#RibbonContainer-TabRowRight` div via JavaScript, but I haven't looked into it.